# How to find an example such that the improper integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\,d x\neq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(i/n)$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How to find an example such that the improper integral $\int_0^1 f(x) \, d x=I$ exists, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(i/n)$ doe not exist or exists but not equal to $I$.

If $f$ is monotone, then it is well-known that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(i/n)=I$. Then we should consider non-monotone one. say $1/x \sin 1/x$. But it seems to hard to consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(i/n)$.

Comment: @Surb your function is monotone, so it is the equal sign.

Comment: If you could show that $\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(i/n)$ "looks like" $\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(i/n)$, where the integral of $g$ over $[0,1]$ diverges. Does this make sense? Perhaps you can try to find a function $f$ such that you may take $g(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x}}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer your function is monotone, so it is the equal sign.

Comment: Is the integral Lebesgue or Riemann? If Lebesgue, just consider the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function).

Comment: @xldd When I wrote the comment, the Riemann sum went from $1$ to $n$, not only to $n-1$. At that point we had $2 \neq +\infty$.